# Вернуть заполненный массив из AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

Есть код, который обесечивает получение данных из WCF-службы. Он работает, из службы получается JSON-строка, которая парсится и выводится на экран.

Я хочу данными из этой строки заполнить класс, и использовать его дальше, вне блока AsynkTask, но не могу его "вытащить" из этого блока. Как это сделать?

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    public static String LOG_TAG = "my_log";
    AutoCompleteTextView txtSearch;
    List<Fruit> mList;
    FruitAdapter adapter;
    public List<Fruit> retrievePeople;//массив, который надо возвращать

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        new ParseTask1().execute();
        mList = retrievePeople;
    }

    public void BTN_click(View view) {
        new ParseTask1().execute();
    }

    //код для чтения из WCF
    private class ParseTask1 extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        String resultJson = "";

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                URL url = new URL("http://192.168.1.94:8080/Test.svc/jsonaray");

                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                urlConnection.connect();

                InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    buffer.append(line);
                }

                resultJson = buffer.toString();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return resultJson;
        }

        //получаем json-массив, распарсиваем его и читаем
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String resultJson){
            super.onPostExecute(resultJson);

            Log.d(LOG_TAG, resultJson);
            JSONObject dataJsonObj = null;
            String Name = "";
            try {
                String resj=resultJson.substring(1,resultJson.length()-1);
                resj=resj.replace("\\","");
                dataJsonObj = new JSONObject(resj);
                JSONArray arr = dataJsonObj.getJSONArray("Prod");

                // 1. достаем инфо о элементе с индексом 1
                JSONObject secondFriend = arr.getJSONObject(3);
                Name = secondFriend.getString("Name");
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Название: " + Name);

                // 2. здесь идет заполнение массива, который надо вернуть
                for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject obj = arr.getJSONObject(i);

                    String _name = obj.getString("Name");
                    String _expiry = obj.getString("Expiry");

                    retrievePeople = new ArrayList<Fruit>();
                    retrievePeople.add(new Fruit(_name,_expiry));

                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "name: " + _name);
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "data: " + _expiry);

                }
                EditText editText =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
                editText.setText(Name);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: А какой конкретно объект Вам нужно «вернуть»? Если я правильно понимаю, то Вы имеете ввиду `retrievePeople`, но это совсем *не массив*. Вы объявили `retrievePeople` как поле класса (точнее говоря, не класса, а объекта класса) `MainActivity` с модификатором `public`, следовательно оно видимо везде.

Comment: И еще, `retrievePeople = new ArrayList<Fruit>();` следует выполнить как минимум перед циклом, ибо у Вас на каждой итерации цикла создается новый объект, который в итоге будет содержать только (один) последний элемент.

Comment: @post_zeew, public List<Fruit> retrievePeople; - я объявляю массив класса Fruit, разве нет? Да, он имеет модификатор доступа public, и он доступен везде. Когда в блоке AsyncTask я его заполняю - он заполняется, но затем, в mList = retrievePeople;, которое происходит после заполнения этого массива, retrievePeople оказывается пустым

Comment: Нет. Массив это `Fruit[] retrievePeople;`, у Вас же `List<Fruit> retrievePeople`, а конкретнее `ArrayList` – это список. Вот это вот `mList = retrievePeople` выполняется сразу после запуска асинстаска, и вполне возможно (даже скорее всего), что в этот момент в `retrievePeople` содержится лишь `null`. Вы же новый поток запускаете, ну. И эти два потока выполняются **асинхронно**.

Comment: `mList = retrievePeople;` можете прописать в конце метода `onPostExecute(...)`, тогда получите желаемое (правда я совсем не понимаю смысл этих хитрых манипуляций).

Comment: @post_zeew, хм, видно совсем из головы вылетело, что асинктаск парралельно выполняется. Спасибо, попробую. Смысл таков: я пока тестирую этот код, так как мне надо будет данные выдернутые из WCF-ки в асинктаске использовать в коде в дальнейшем, вот и все

Comment: Вы второй комментарий внимательно прочитайте, а то не получите всех данных.

Comment: Я все прочитал, понял что надо исправить, благодарю

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как выяснилось из комментариев, вопрос был в том, почему в методе `onCreate(...)` данные не загружаются в `mList` в строке `mList = retrievePeople;`.

А не загружаются они потому, что на момент выполнения строки `mList = retrievePeople;` в `retrievePeople` этих данных еще нет. Данные в `retrievePeople` загружаются в другом потоке (уже после того, как будет выполнено `mList = retrievePeople;`).

Answer (score 1):

попробуйте так

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    public static String LOG_TAG = "my_log";
    AutoCompleteTextView txtSearch;
    List<Fruit> mList;
    FruitAdapter adapter;
    public List<Fruit> retrievePeople;//массив, который надо возвращать

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        new ParseTask1().execute();
        mList = retrievePeople;
    }

    public void BTN_click(View view) {
      // .......
    }

    public void asyncFinished() {
       mList = retrievePeople; // !!!!!!!!!!
           // делаете что хотите со списком. он теперь тут
    }

    //код для чтения из WCF
    private class ParseTask1 extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        String resultJson = "";

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
          // .......
        }

        //получаем json-массив, распарсиваем его и читаем
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String resultJson){
            super.onPostExecute(resultJson);

            Log.d(LOG_TAG, resultJson);
            JSONObject dataJsonObj = null;
            String Name = "";
            try {
                String resj=resultJson.substring(1,resultJson.length()-1);
                resj=resj.replace("\\","");
                dataJsonObj = new JSONObject(resj);
                JSONArray arr = dataJsonObj.getJSONArray("Prod");

                // 1. достаем инфо о элементе с индексом 1
                JSONObject secondFriend = arr.getJSONObject(3);
                Name = secondFriend.getString("Name");
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Название: " + Name);

                // 2. здесь идет заполнение массива, который надо вернуть
                retrievePeople = new ArrayList<Fruit>(); // !!!!!!
                for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject obj = arr.getJSONObject(i);

                    String _name = obj.getString("Name");
                    String _expiry = obj.getString("Expiry");    

                    retrievePeople.add(new Fruit(_name,_expiry));

                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "name: " + _name);
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "data: " + _expiry);

                }
                EditText editText =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
                editText.setText(Name);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            asyncFinished();
        }
    }

}
```